# Проблема в отображении FileResponse, содержащем сгенерированный pdf, на web-странице в теге <embed>

Tags: django, ajax, pdf, blob, response

Всем доброго времени суток.
Пишется приложение на django, которое должно из введенных в форму на странице данных, на этой же странице отобразить сгенерированный с помощью reportlab pdf-файл.
Страница разбита на два блока с помощью колонок bootstrap, во второй колонке есть элемент embed c пустым параметром src
По нажатию на ссылку выполняется ajax запрос на сервер, который отсылает данные из формы, сервер (то бишь view на django), обрабатывает данные, формирует pdf в виде массива байтов (BytesIO) и отправляет результат в виде FileResponse. success в ajax'e принимает ответ, создает blob объект, на основе blob формирует ссылку на файл и присваивает эту ссылку параметру src embed. В итоге pdf файл отображается, но отображает белеберду (есть подозрения на неверное кодирование файла). Помогите советом, испробовал много вариантов. Есть нюанс, если присваивать {% url <ну и так далее> %} в параметр src, то все отображается верно, но нюанс в том, что таким способом нельзя передать значения формы в представление, так как поля формы динамические, и их количество и наличие всегда разное (детали создаваемого приложения, долго описывать). Отсюда вывод, что использование ajax обязательно, отталкиваться нужно от этого.
Ниже приложу коды.
страница:

```
{% block Content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <h2>{{ caption }}</h2>
                <form class="form-control" method="post" id="document_form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <span id="myForm">{{ form|crispy }}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">{{ caption }}</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href={{ back_url }}>Назад</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#" onclick="updateFrame2()">Просмотр</a>
                </form>
                <a class="btn-danger" id="mybtn" href="#" onclick="get_pdf()">TEST</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <embed id="frameDoc" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" src="">

                </embed>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block JavaScript %}
    <script defer src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.7.1.js' %}"></script>
    <script defer src="{% static 'js/print.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
{#    работает верно, но не подходит #}
        function updateFrame2() {
            document.getElementById(`frameDoc`).src = '{% url 'MyApp:MakeReport' %}';
        };
        function get_pdf() {
            const formdata = $('#document_form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/makereport/",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#document_form').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    var blob = new Blob([data,], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                    let link = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    document.getElementById(`frameDoc`).src = link;
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log('error');
                },
            });
        };
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

view:

```
@xframe_options_exempt
def MakeReport(request):
    # все приведенные манипуляции на самом деле не важны
    # так как pdf() возвращает BytesIO( параметр seek=0)
    json = UserDocs.objects.get(id=1).make_json_with_parameters()
    requisites = [Requisite(**req) for req in json]
    pdf = PDFDocument()
    for req in requisites:
        pdf.add_requisite(req)
    pdf.build_doc()
    # единственный нюанс в том, что pdf нигде не хранится физически на диске,
    # поэтому ссылку на файл тоже не получится сделать
    return FileResponse(pdf(), as_attachment=False, filename='test.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, спасибо всем за участие, решается так:

```
function get_pdf() {
            const formdata = $('#document_form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/privatecabinet/makereport/",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#document_form').serialize(),
                xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    let link2 = URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    document.getElementById(`frameDoc`).src = link2;
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log('error');
                },
            });
        };
```